# Strange sql behavior - last character is removed in the Select statement, but actual data has different length

Tags: oracle

We have a table with a column name `A` with type `nvarchar(23)`.

following query will always return `23` which means that the actual length of all records are `23`.

```
select length(trim(req.A)), count(*)
  from tableName req
group by length(trim(req.A));
```

```
|length(trim(req.A))|count(*)| 
------------------------------
|23                 |1006    |
```

But when we select from this table with following query it behaves different and it seems that the last character is always removed in result Gridview in the pl/sql developer.

```
select LENGTHB(req.A) lenb, length(req.A) len, req.* from tableName req
where req.A = 'NHBBBBB1398052635902235'; -- Note to the equal sign and the last charactar (5) of the where clause
```

the result is:

```
|lenb|len|          A           |
---------------------------------
|46  |23 |NHBBBBB139805263590223|
```

As you can see the last character (**`5`**) is removed in the select result.

Also when we rewrite previous query with `to_char()` or run it in `sqlplus` it works fine & return correct result with the length of **`23`** and (**`5`**) as the last character.

```
select LENGTHB(req.A) lenb, length(req.A) len, to_char(req.A) from tableName req
where req.A = 'NHBBBBB1398052635902235';
```

the result is:

```
|lenb|len|    to_char(req.A)     |
----------------------------------
|46  |23 |NHBBBBB1398052635902235|
```

Can you please explain whats happen!? Is this related to pl/sql configs? How to solve this?

Comment: What happens when you run the queries in sqlplus?

Comment: @Colin'tHart unfortunately, the db is on our customer environment and we don't have direct access to it. They denied to run this query in sqlplus.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in question? What is the database character set?

Comment: What if you try this? ```
select LENGTHB(req.A) lenb, length(req.A) len, req.* from tableName req
where req.A = N'NHBBBBB1398052635902235';
``` A literal in between quotes is created as VARCHAR2. If you put the "N" before the quote, it will be created as NVARCHAR2.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem was an **old version of PL/SQL Developer** which our customers used. When they updated to the newer version, the problem has been solved.